# Differences beetween *a = b and a = &b?

Tags: c, pointers

What are the differences, if any, between

```
*a = b;
```

and

```
a = &b;
```

Are these two different ways to make a var point to another var?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense without any context. What are `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they do not do the same thing. `*a = b;` does not change `a` but it changes what `a` points to. `a = &b;` does change `a` but it does not change what `a` pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different operations.

`*a = b` copies the value of `b` into the memory location pointed by `a`.

`a = &b` changes `a` so that now `a` points to the location of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

`*a = b` means copy value of `b` in the adress pointed by `a`

`a = &b` means `a` now points to `b`

Answer (score 1):

The following peace of code should Answer to your Question:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int  main(void){
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;

    int *p = &b;
    printf("A = %d\nB = %d\n*p = %d\n",a,b,*p);

    *p = a;
    printf("\n");
    printf("A = %d\nB = %d\n*p = %d\n",a,b,*p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> A = 5
> B = 10
> *p = 10
> ```

```
A = 5
B = 5
*p = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As a small example:

```
int b=10,c=20;
int *a=0;
a=&b; *a=c;
```

Now you changed the value of b to to value of c

Comment: What's the difference beetwen int *a = 0 and int a = 0?